# Unable to use lastmodifieddate in the WHERE clause in netsuite2.com SQL query

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to run a query against netsuite2.com as following:

```
select lastmodifieddate from transaction where lastmodifieddate>'2016-06-16 18:50:50'
```

But this produces an error:

```
[NetSuite][SuiteAnalytics Connect JDBC Driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Failed to retrieve data. Error ticket# kybpw8j91333lgz1ovora[400]
```

p.s. I am using NQjc.jar JDBC driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has to do with the datetime settings on the account being used to connect to the analytics schema.  To make sure it works for all cases, use the to_date function to convert the string representation into a sql `datetime` object:

```
select lastmodifieddate from transaction 
where lastmodifieddate > to_date('2016-06-16 18:50:50', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while working working with a NetSuite ODBC via Azure Data Factory Pipeline. I tried the `to_date()` approach, but it did not work. I was getting the following error:

> Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [S1000] [NetSuite][ODBC 64bit driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Failed to retrieve data. Error ticket# lggq6m75keahp9wgn87v[400],Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [S1000] [NetSuite][ODBC 64bit driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Failed to retrieve data. Error ticket# lggq6m75keahp9wgn87v[400],Source=NQoa27.dll,'

I found another method which seems working; I used:

```
TO_CHAR(lastmodifieddate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > '2016-06-16 18:50:50';
```

I found this info via: https://timdietrich.me/blog/netsuite-suiteql-dates-times/